# Update database table values with user defined date and time

Tags: mongodb, auto-update, database

can i update database value with user defined date and time? i don't want create Cron jobs for this update .is any way to implement update with user defined date and time? iam using mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You can use Events for that purpose

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT "2015-02-10 23:59:00"
    DO UPDATE user SET mycol = mycol + 1;
```

Read more about events [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html)